# PLSQL Oracle 10 - executing a stored proc

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure, but I'm not sure if my syntax is wrong or not.

```
set dbms_output.put_line on;

declare
  v_premnum NUMBER(10);
  v_util_type CHAR(10);
  v_result VARCHAR2(200);

Begin
  execute myprocedure( 'E', v_util_type, 73105 , v_premnum);
  dbms_output.put_line = v_result
end;

/
```

Comment: remove the `execute`. `myprocedure( 'E', v_util_type, 73105 , v_premnum);` is enough.

Comment: and change `dbms_output.put_line = v_result` to `dbms_output.put_line(v_result);`

Comment: is not v_result null ? where do you assign anything to it ? 
and what about v_premnum  and v_util_type ? are they OUT parameters or what ?

Comment: `put_line` has no "result".

Comment: Thanks all, v_premnum and v_util_type are input values, V_result is an output value.

Comment: So, Now I have the following.  set dbms_output.put_line on;

declare
v_premnum NUMBER(10);
v_util_type CHAR(10);
v_result VARCHAR2(200);

Begin
myprocedure( 'E', v_util_type, 73105 , v_premnum);

dbms_output.put_line = (v_result);

end;

Comment: You still need to read @Przemyslaw's comment Ben.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways. Either your procedure has an output parameter:

```
declare
  v_premnum NUMBER(10) := 1234;
  v_util_type CHAR(10) := 'the type';
  v_result VARCHAR2(200);
begin
  myprocedure('E', v_util_type, 73105 , v_premnum, v_result);
  dbms_output.put_line(v_result);
end;
```

Or it should be a function returning the desired value:

```
declare
  v_premnum NUMBER(10) := 1234;
  v_util_type CHAR(10) := 'the type';
  v_result VARCHAR2(200);
begin
  v_result := myfunction('E', v_util_type, 73105 , v_premnum);
  dbms_output.put_line(v_result);
end;
```